# Can I load a new form into panel?

Tags: c#, panel, frontend, windows

I am working on Windows Application.I am having a menustrip in one form and I want to ask that, can I have a panel which will load new form on particular click of menustripitem.

Ex:

```
File Data 
  ABC  Hello
  XYZ  Bye
```

These is my menu bar.On click of ABC I dont want to go on different form can I do something
(whatever I want to)on the same form using panel.

Thanks

Comment: Much better to use UserControls instead of Forms.

Answer (score 4):

I think that I had the same question.

But I found the answer for it

[CodeProject Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/414107/Csharp-Form-inside-a-Panel)

First you have to configurate the Form:

```
myForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

And then, manipulates the action:

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
myForm.TopLevel = false;
myForm.AutoScroll = true;
frmMain.Panel2.Controls.Add(myForm);
myForm.Show();
```

Hope to help you. Hugs :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171654.aspx) Form. 
Try something like this

```
 //Create a new instance of the MDI child template form
    Form2 child= new Form2(); 

    //Set parent form for the child window 
    child.MdiParent=this;

    //Display the child window
    child.Show()
```

you can also refer to this [site](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57601-using-mdi-in-c#/).

Answer (score 0):

If you put the whole content of the target form into a UserControl, you can add a panel to your main form and place the UserControl on that panel.

You still have option to display a separate form by creating an empty form and placing the same UserControl on that form, too.

As Int3 ὰ already points out, you could use MDI forms instead. However, if you want to use dockable panels, the UserControl would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add two panels on your form, only one will be visible at the same time. Then, add two events on your menus:

```
private void ABCToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    panelABC.Visible = true;
    panelXYZ.Visible = false;
}

private void XYZToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    panelABC.Visible = false;
    panelXYZ.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void pbxpurchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contentpnl.Controls.Clear();//contentpnl is the panelname
        purchasebook purchasebk = new purchasebook();//purchasebook is a formname
        purchasebk.TopLevel = false;
        purchasebk.AutoScroll = true;
        contentpnl.Controls.Add(purchasebk);
        purchasebk.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        purchasebk.Show();

    }
```

try this 100%  tested